# etags and server farm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, caching, scalability

I gathered from the much famed scaling rails screencasts that at some point when your  site gets big and bigger, proxy caching is the way to go. Proxy caching uses etag, among other things and since etags can be more specific and strong validator is perhaps the way to go. However, I also hear that in server farm scenarios the etag is not the right solution because it can vary across servers (How?)

This seems contradictory i.e. most likely one is implementing e-tag based proxy caching if they are running a large load balanced server farms. So if e-tag fails in this situation how do they do it? :last_modified isn't really a great option.

In a rails app let's say if my etags in a post index action is

```
:etag => "all_posts_#{Post.count}".
```

will this vary from server to server if it's a load balanced server farm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually when they talk about Etags varying across servers it's in relation to static connect served up by Apache. By default [Apache includes the file's inode in the Etag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#fileetag). If the files are not on a shared resource (like a NFS exported NAS), then the file's inode would be different on each server.  Typically, the recommendation is to configure Apache like:

```
FileETag MTime Size
```

but even that has the possibility of differences if the modification time varies across the servers.

However, for non-static content, you are generating the Etag in your code, so it would be the same across multiple servers.

Comment: Thanks! Very re-assuring :). How does it normally play well nginx and other reverse proxies, is it pretty straightforward or are there gotachas (like apaches here)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. Do you mean Apache behind a reverse proxy, or do you mean nginx behind a reverse proxy? Or do you mean configuring etags for nginx? Unless something has changed recently, I don't believe nginx supports generating etags for static content.Typically, etags are not as useful for static content as the last-modified header can trivially be generated for such content. Etags are more useful for dynamic content that doesn't have a definite "last modified" date.

Comment: yes sorry a bit confusing, look at my other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860343/reverse-proxy-confusion. But I am essentially trying to figure out how to reverse proxy cache my current set up(nginx + passenger, nginx used as a web server). I would like to be serving both static (images) content and etagged dynamic content from a reverse proxy (tbd, whether nginx can perform the role of both reverse proxy/web server or would I need multiple nginx installations or would I need a different product as a reverse with this set up). Hopefully that helps?