# reverse proxy confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, caching, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

Currently I use nginx + passenger for serving my rails app. I have been doing some research on reverse proxies and a few names pop up (squid, varnish and nginx mostly).

1. Now If I am using nginx as my
   web server can I stil use it as my
   reverse proxy?
2. The general sense is that most
   sites use nginx for proxying static
   content and apache/mongrel or
   something like that for dynamic
   content. If I wanna stick with my
   nginx, passenger setup, what would
   my architecture look like when I
   introduce a reverse proxy? Will it
   be a separate box or instance of
   nginx?
3. What would it look like if I am
   introducing a load balancer like
   HAProxy.
4. Finally, how important are these
   choices early on? So If I end up
   regretting a choice (let's say
   Varnish because it doesn't do well
   with cookies etc etc), is it easy to
   switch things around?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A reverse proxy is a server that sits between your actual app (rails) and the client's browser, and retrieves files on behalf of the client. What is needed to configure a reverse proxy is only to set up a server between the client and the app; since you are already using nginx you can use it as a reverse proxy also.

**1** here's a link on SO: [nginx be both reverse proxy and web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912342/nginx-be-both-reverse-proxy-and-web-server)

**2** You can set up a reverse proxy in the same instance or not. If it is a different box or process, you'll need to pass dynamic requests from one box to another.

**4** I think it's fairly easy, if you are familiar with both HTTP and configuring those servers. I had a hard time with apache just because I missed a trailing slash